# Connect to SFTP server that does not support openSSH key format

Tags: sftp, ssh-keys, openssh

I suppose that answer is "No" but I need somebody clever and wise to confirm it.
We have a SFTP server (host) and use .ppk private key to connect to it from another server (guest). The first (host) SFTP server does not support openSSH format. But now we need to use a cloud solution instead of the second (guest) server and it does not support .ppk key format. I can convert it to .pem format. But will it fit to its old public key that is saved on the SFTP server?
Thank you in advance.

Not a problem to convert the key format, but I don't understand if I can use public and private key when they are in different formats.

Comment: I'm not sure, what you mean by "the server doesn't support openssh key format"? SSH is a fixed protocol. The "private key format" is a pure client side (ie whether you use an openSSH based client or putty). The information sent to the server has always to be the same. Otherwise, no putty client would be capable of connecting to an openSSH based server and vice versa

Comment: Yes, it might be, that for your server config you have to store your keys in putty's key format, but the information for the key must always be the same, regardless what format is used ...

Comment: Thank you very much.
Yes, this is most likely about server config - it is a third party server. And I got an answer from them "we do not support open SSH"

Comment: But does it mean that I can connect from our cloud solution (we wanted to use Azure Logic Apps) using private key in .pem format ?

Comment: Impossible to say without further details. But this question is probably off topic here anyways. Maybe try at https://superuser.com